# How to I create a code in Python to run a file A, use its output as input to file B?

Tags: python-2.7

A and B are independent files which run perfectly. They are coded such that the results are stored in corresponding text files. My requirement is to create a new code to run the file A, get its output and give it as the input to the file B and run it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
# File1 
def do_something(in_file):
    with open(in_file, "r") as t:
        return t.name
# File2
def do_something_else(in_file):
    with open(in_file, 'r') as q:
        for a in q.readlines():
            print(a)

# File to Run Other Files

import file1, file2

outfile = file1.do_something("hello.txt")
file2.do_something_else(outfile)
```

The value which is returned from file1 is a full file path so when doing your code you can either return the path from the file object as I have or you can pass the file name (which you used to create the output file).

Bear in mind all these files should be in the same directory.